# What is the difference between Mage:getModel and Mage:getModelInstance?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I am using almost all time `Mage:getModel`. But surprisingly i found somewhere about `Mage:getModelInstance`.

Can you please tell me where to use `Mage:getModelInstance` and what is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that `getModel` can be called from `Mage` whereas `getModelInstance` is a method from the `Config` class only : https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L1341

[`getModel` actually calls `getModelInstance`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/Mage.php#L463) so there is no reason for calling the second one